# A word to describe a new item added a completed sequence

Tags: word-choice

We all know the item before the last is penultimate, but what about adding to a sequence that is effectively closed?

'Postultimate' maybe? this seems right but I cannot find any usages. 'Next' is certainly descriptive as are 'subsequent', 'following' and 'succeeding' but these words do not convey the /fact that the sequence was considered complete before the new item was added.

Practical applications could include adding a new letter to the alphabet (unlikely I know but go with it for a moment - no trolling!) or new elements added to the periodic table.

The case in question, the one which prompted this question, is software related. An application we had created was considered complete, updates were no longer being worked on and the current functionality would never be changed (however there are still active users so it was very much alive). Then, for reasons I will not go into, an update (the one after the last ever) was needed.

Maybe the the word 'postultimate' could also be used to describe an aging pop star's comeback tour after they had already retired, though this may draw us into antipostultimate and postantepostultiamte hell!

What fun!

Comment: Would *update* or *patch* work in your specific example? In non-technical usage, software updates and patches aren't treated 'new versions'. If someone is using a Windows 7 system that's been patched and updated many times, try asking them what *version* of Windows they're using. I'm pretty sure the reply would, more often than not, specify "7" but not the patch/update number.

Comment: Slightly relevant trivia: the OED recently added a "_postultimate_" word: **_Zyzzyva_** (meaning "_genus of tropical American weevils_") is its new last word . See [OED announcement](http://public.oed.com/the-oed-today/recent-updates-to-the-oed/june-2017-update/new-words-notes-june-2017/).

Answer (score 1):

It used to be the case that, a software or game that is "complete" is **Gold Edition**, and should the developers find stuff they want to fix or implement later on they usually bundle all of them together and call it a **Platinum Edition**. These days though, those words have almost lost their meaning.

Of course, you could have already called your software "XYZ Final Edition", then all you need to do is to call it a remaster (not a software update, a graphical or auditory update) and put a few new graphics here and there along with the software update.

If there are no graphics or audio in your program or you don't want to make new ones just to call it a remaster, then I'd suggest not using any word for it at all. If it's a bugfix update, call it that. If it's a feature update, call it that. If it's just an overhaul, call it a major update and give a newer version number. Just be honest with your customers "We thought this was the final version, but as time went on, technology has progressed and we wanted to keep up with the times. So, we went back and reworked our codes and ironed out bugs and-" yada yada yada. That part is up to you.

Comment: Sounds like the ultimate **2.0**.

Answer (score 1):

I like "postultimate".
For example: In music key signatures

For flats: Key is penultimate note in key signature
E.G.  four flats = B E A D = Ab maj

For sharps: key is the note after the last note in key signature, i.e. the postultimate,
E.g. four sharps = F C G D = Emaj

Answer (score 0):

In light of the United States Constitution, **amendment** would be suitable here.

> A minor change or addition designed to improve a text, piece of legislation, etc. - [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/amendment)

Note that when capitalised, *Amendment* implies one of the [27 Amendments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_amendments_to_the_United_States_Constitution) to the aforementioned US Constitution.